# Need to split Team project collection in TFS 2012

Tags: team-project-collection

This is an exam specific scenario as I am preparing for 70-496 exam.
Suppose I have Team project collection and I want to split the collection in two Team projects collection and move few of project to new collection. as per exam video's on microsoftvirtualacademy site, power tools are not recommended.
What can be other possible ways to do this?

I know one way 
1)In the TFS Administration Console, create a new empty team project collection.
2)Use the TFS Integration Platform to copy the required team projects to the new team project collection.

but this using power tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by detaching the collection, cloning the database, reattaching as 2 collections, then selectively deleting team projects.

It's all described in this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936158(v=vs.120).aspx